# Linux copy directory structure and create symlinks to existing files with different extension

Tags: bash

I have a large directory structure similar to the following

```
/home/user/abc/src1
                   /file_a.xxx
                   /file_b.xxx
/home/user/abc/src2
                   /file_a.xxx
                   /file_b.xxx
```

It contains multiple srcX folders and has many files, most of the files have a .xxx extension. These are the ones that I am interested in.

I would like to create an identical directory structure in say /tmp. This part I have been able to accomplish via rsync

```
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" /home/user/abc/ /tmp/xyz/
```

The next step is what I can't figure out. I need the directory structure in /tmp/xyz to have symlinks to all the files in /home/user/abc with a different file extension (.zzz). The directory structure would look as follows:

```
/tmp/xyz/src1
             /file_a.zzz -> /home/user/abc/src1/file_a.xxx
             /file_b.zzz -> /home/user/abc/src1/file_b.xxx
/tmp/xyz/src2
             /file_a.zzz -> /home/user/abc/src2/file_a.xxx
             /file_b.zzz -> /home/user/abc/src2/file_b.xxx
```

I understand that I could just copy the data and do a batch rename. That is not an acceptable solution.

How do I recursively create symlinks for all the .xxx files in /home/user/abc and link them to /tmp/xyz with a .zzz extension.

The find + exec seems like what I want but I can't put 2 and 2 together on this one.

Answer (score 1):

This could work

```
cd /tmp/xyz/src1
find /home/user/abc/src1/ -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 -I '{}' ln -s '{}' $(basename '{}' .xxx).zzz
```

Comment: Did you test this? I don't think the `$(basename '{}' .xxx)` part works.

Comment: yes, it works. Just tested it to be honest. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `/tmp/xyz/` then run the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# First make src* folders in present directory:                                          
mkdir -p $(find ~/user/abc/src* -type d -name "src*" | rev | cut -d"/" -f1 | rev)

# Then make symbolic links:
while read -r -d' ' file; do                                     
    ln -s  ${file} $(echo ${file} | rev | cut -d/ -f-2 | rev  | sed 's/\.xxx/\.zzz/')            
done <<< $(echo "$(find ~/user/abc/src* -type f -name '*.xxx') dummy")
```

Comment: That is an ingenious use of rev and cut

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input all. Based upon the ideas I saw I was able to come up with a script that fits my needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

GLOBAL_SRC_DIR="/home/usr/abc"
GLOBAL_DEST_DIR="/tmp/xyz"

create_symlinks ()
{
    local SRC_DIR="${1}"
    local DEST_DIR="${2}"

    # read in our file, use null terminator
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do

            # If file ends with .xxx or .yyy
            if [[ ${file} =~ .*\.(xxx|yyy) ]] ; then
                    basePath="$(dirname ${file})"
                    fileName="$(basename ${file})"
                    completeSourcePath="${basePath}/${fileName}"
                    #echo "${completeSourcePath}"

                    # strip off preceding text
                    partialDestPath=$(echo ${basePath} | sed -r "s|^${SRC_DIR}||" )
                    fullDestPath="${DEST_DIR}/${partialDestPath}"

                    # rename file from .xxx to .zzz. don't rename just link .yyy
                    cppFileName=$(echo ${fileName} | sed -r "s|\.xxx$|\.zzz|" )
                    completeDestinationPath="${fullDestPath}/${cppFileName}"

                    $(ln -s ${completeSourcePath} ${completeDestinationPath})
            fi
    done < <(find ${SRC_DIR} -type f -print0)
}

main ()
{
    create_symlinks ${GLOBAL_SRC_DIR} ${GLOBAL_DEST_DIR}
}

main
```